# How to download updated sqlite Database from AWS EB? (Django app)

Tags: django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my django app on AWS Elastic beanstalk, using the sqlite database.  The site has been running for a while.

Now I have made some changes to the website and want to deploy again, but by keeping the changes the database went through(by form inputs)

But I am not able to find a way to download the updated database or any files. The only version of the app I am able to download is the one I already uploaded when I first deployed.

How can I download the current running app version and deploy with the same database?

Comment: Normally you deploy by updating the code of your website and then apply your migrations by running `manage.py migrate`. Your migrations don't delete any data from your database (unless you specifically make them to). You don't need to download your database. Please specify how you're "deploying" your website.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why are you using sqlite in production, rather than one of the many aws hosted db options? Why do you want to download it? Why can't you simply run the migrations?

Comment: Note: to create a dump of your database before trying something that might be destructive you can use `dumpdata` (link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata))

Comment: I am not using AWS databases but sqlite one which is generally used in development. Is there a way to download this database, or is it better practice to use the AWS databases?

Comment: You should be able to just run your migrations. Like on your local machine. But yes, for the long run you should not use sqlite, it's for development purposes. To switch to a different db, use `dumpdata` and `loaddata`.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you why to download your db, and why you can't just run the migrations in prod.

Comment: When I deploy the app the database also gets rewritten, since the sqlite database is in the zip folder. I can run migrations on development and upload but I need to keep the data which is in current running version of database

Comment: What? Why? Why would you include the db in the deployment in the first place? Even if you wanted to stay with sqlite on production, you shouldn't deploy the db file, it should be created - and subsequently modified - by your migrations.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am doing that right now.

Answer (score 0):

you may use scp to connect to remote server and download all your files.

as commented, you should better use `dumpdata` and then i/o that file (instead of the db or full site).

however, if your remote system python version is not the same as your django site, then the dumpdata may not work (this is my case), so I managed to download the whole site folder back to local and then use `dumpdata`

aws elastic beanstalk Python app's files in `/opt/python/current/app`

just use `scp -r` to download the whole site to local.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have sqlite db file being packaged from your local during eb deploy. If that is a case then all you need to do is not include db.sqlite file in your deployments.

Move location of db.sqllite file to s3 or ebs persistent volume so that it persists.

Use .ebextentions to run db migration in aws on top of the aws db file just the way django recommends.

To be on safe side you can ssh into your eb env which is ec2 instance and download db.sqlite file just incase.